# How to search a sub-folder for a particular text file

Tags: vb.net, text-files

I have a folder titled ‘The Arts’ which contains various sub-folders, one of which is titled ‘Music’. This ‘Music’ sub-folder contains various text files in the format:

John Doe.TXT

John Lennon.TXT

Elton John.TXT

Now, on my Form, I have two Textboxes in which the user can enter the names of artists like so;

Textbox1.Text = John

Textbox2.Text = Lennon

What I want to achieve is that on clicking a button on this form, the program searches the ‘The Arts’ parent folder for the ‘Music’ sub-folder and then searches within this music sub-folder for the text file name which exactly matches the artist name concatenated from Textboxes 1 and 2.

If a text file name exactly matches the artist name concatenated from Textboxes 1 and 2, then display a message. If no text file name within the Music sub-folder matches the name concatenated from Textboxes 1 and 2; then display a message that no file is found.

The below code is incomplete and just shows how I specified the main file path. I do not know how to proceed to get the program to do the above.

I am using Visual Basic 2010 Express. Thank you for your help.

```vb
Dim FilePath As String
        FilePath = (Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), "The Arts\"))

        'This section is where I am stuck and need help...Thank you in advance.

        If File.Exists(FilePath) Then
            MsgBox("File found.")
        Else
            MsgBox("A record does not exist for this artist.")
            Exit Sub
        End If
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to check if a text file name exactly matches the artist name concatenated from Textboxes 1 and 2

You need to first concatenate the text from the text boxes, that given your example, need to be separated by a space. There are a few ways to accomplish that.

For example like [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/te2585xw.aspx):

```
Dim artistName = TextBox1.Text + " " + TextBox2.Text
```

Or [this](http://www.dotnetperls.com/string-concat-vbnet):

```
Dim artistName = String.Concat(TextBox1.Text, " ", TextBox2.Text)
```

And there are even more ways to do this.

Next you will need to assemble this into a full file path name. For readability it makes sense to do this in a few steps:

```
' Directory
Dim desktopPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop)
Dim musicPath = Path.Combine(deskTopPath, "The Arts", "Music"))

' Combine directory name and the name of the file we want to find.
Dim filePath = Path.Combine(musicPath, artistName + ".TXT")
```

Finally you can check whether that file exists by calling the [`File.Exists` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.exists(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1).

```
Dim found = File.Exists(filePath)
```

Comment: Many thanks for your help, Alex. Your suggestion worked for me. Also, please if it is not too much to ask; would you happen to know how I can programmatically read the name of the sub-folder the program is reading from and display this name in a textbox on the form? Thanks again.

Comment: You need to use google a bit more so you can figure these things out for yourself. Like searching for "file information vb.net" or "folder information vb.net".

Comment: Thank you for your earlier assistance. I had been to Google before asking my first and second questions and didn't really find what I was looking for. That was why I proceeded to ask this on this forum. But yea, thanks. I have been able to figure out a way to address the second question I asked you. Cheers.